# Anything like recyclerview or reusable views for javafx

Tags: javafx, android-recyclerview, fxml

I am creating a scrollpane which display sets of data which is fetched from a sqlite db and these data are display in such a way that they arranged in repeated set of ui like in recyclerview in android.
Is there any way to achieve it because its not easy to position elements using javafx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few classes that work with similar concepts in javafx:

- [`ListView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html)
- [`TableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html)
- [`TreeView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeView.html)
- [`TreeTableView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableView.html)

The adapter is replaced by the `cellFactory`(s), position does not really have an equivalent, the cells do contain a `index` property though. There is a `updateItem` method in the `Cell` class that is responsible for updating the cell visuals.

Please use some tutorials to become familiar with those kind of controls, since this is beyond the scope of an answer.

`ListCell` works similar to `TableView`, but there is basically just a single column, and the `cellFactory` is a property of the `ListView` class itself and there is no `cellValueFactory` equivalent.

`TreeView` and `TreeTableView` work pretty similar to `ListView` and `TableView` respecively, the main difference being the support of a hierarchical data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement my own ListCell, and then use it in a ListView.
It would be something like:

```
public class RecyclerLikeCell extends ListCell<MyCustomBean> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(MyCustomBean item, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        //Create whatever you need to render. And then add:
        //I'm using a VBox as an example, you may use whatever you need.
        var myComponent = new VBox(component1, component2, component3);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        setGraphic(myComponent);
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to use as ListCellFactory.
     *
     * @return a Callback to use in ListView.
     */
    public static Callback<ListView<MyCustomBean>, ListCell<MyCustomBean>>
        forListView(){

        return i -> new RecyclerLikeCell();
    }

}
```

And then, in your controller initialization you can use:

```
listRecyclerView.setCellFactory(RecyclerLikeCell.forListView());
```

And it should be fine. I've used it to create a user menu like the one on SAP Business One GUI.